# Construct an isomorphism from $2\times 2$ matrix to $\mathbf F^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $$V=\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&a+b\\
0&c\\
\end{pmatrix}
:a, b, c\in\mathbf F\}$$
Construct an isomorphism from $V$ to $\mathbf F^3$

I think I have to find a invertible linear map between $V$ and $(x, y, z)\in\mathbf F^3$

But how to find it?

Comment: Not only are three suggestive parameters $a,b,c$ written right there, there is also an obvious way to pick three numbers from a four entries matrix with one entry being zero and "useless". - As in, do you know an isomorphism between the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices and $\mathbf F^4$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I know it. Since one entry is $0$, we can find a map that takes the basis of $V$ to the basis $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)$ of $\mathbf F^3$

Answer (score 0):

You can take$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Psi\colon&\mathbf F^3&\longrightarrow&V\\&(a,b,c)&\mapsto&\begin{bmatrix}a&a+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}.\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$V=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&a+b\\
0&c\\
\end{pmatrix}
\middle| a, b, c\in\mathbf F\right\} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&c\\
\end{pmatrix}
\middle| a, b, c\in\mathbf F\right\}$$ And then it is easy to see this is a $3$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, so a simple isomorphism is $$\varphi \left(  \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}  \right) = \left(a,b,c\right)$$
Note that all you need to do is find a map that takes  basis vectors to basis vectors for two $n$-dimensional vector spaces over a field.